# How to do left join without select

Tags: sql

I have two tables, "user", and "user_things". I want to get all users with one or more things, but I don't want to retrieve the things themselves (I only want one row per user returned).

```
Table 1:
id
username

Table 2:
id
userid
thingname
```

Example: I want to find all users with a "hat" and a "car". If there are two users with this, I want only two rows returned (not 4).

Comment: Use EXISTS(twice) , like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20452973/905902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all users for which a record for 'car' and for 'hat' `exists` in the other table.

```
select
  *
from
  User u
where
  exists (
    select 'x' 
    from Things t 
    where t.userid = u.id and t.thingname = 'hat') and
  exists (
    select 'x' 
    from Things t 
    where t.userid = u.id and t.thingname = 'car')
```

Alternatively, you can do this, although I think it's less nice, less semantically correct:

```
select distinct
  u.*
from
  Users u
  inner join Things tc on tc.userid = u.id and tc.thingname = 'car'
  inner join Things th on th.userid = u.id and th.thingname = 'hat'
```

Or even:

```
select
  u.*
from
  Users u
where
  (select 
    count('x') 
  from Things t
  where t.userid = u.id and t.thingname in ('car', 'hat')) = 2
```

Although the last one might also return users that have no car and two hats.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
select u.userid, u.username
from user u join
     user_things ut
     on ut.userid = u.id
group by t1.userid, t1.username
having sum(case when ut.thingname = 'hat' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when ut.thingname = 'car' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

The first part of the `having` clause counts the number of "hat"s.  The second counts the number of "car"s.  The `>` condition requires that both are present.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is

```
select user.id, user.name
  from user
 inner join things t on t.userid = user.id
 where t.thingname in ('car', 'hat')
 group by user.id, user.name
having count(*) >= 2; -- (2 for 'car' and 'hat', 3 for 'car', 'hat' and 'bike', ...)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b466/6)